# push the data index to an array in Extjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, extjs

my back end data is

```
    "data": [
    {
      "DATE": "2018-02-07",
        "1": "10",          
        "2": "3"
    },
    {
     "DATE": "2018-03-04",
        "1": "1",           
        "2": "5"
    }
]
```

My model part is

```
var companies = ['1', '2'];
Ext.define('O2a.model.management', {

extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [

    {name: 'DATE', type: 'auto'}

].concat(
    companies.map(function(companyName) {
        return {
            name: companyName,
            type: 'int'
        };
    })
),

proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    noCache: false,

    actionMethods: {'read': 'POST'},

    api: {
        read: utils.createUrl('api', 'management-read'),

    },

    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    },

    ...
```

Instead of defining `var companies = ['1', '2'];` in model part it needs to push the data of my back end code into the array whatever the index values coming except the date.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You question is not clear the requirement can you explain exact requirement ?

Comment: here I am defining the companies '1', '2' inside companies array in my model. But my I can be able to get the data from my back end as  "data": [
    {
      "DATE": "2018-02-07",
        "1": "10",          
        "2": "3"
    },
    {
     "DATE": "2018-03-04",
        "1": "1",           
        "2": "5"
    }
]    So instead of hard code the things inside an array I do want to push it to the array.. Because the data part may change time to time. So can't hard code.

Comment: Please put required output here

Comment: let me clear it again if I got the data in backend like                    data: [
  { date: '2018-12-20', company1: 10, company2: 5, },
  { date: '2018-12-21', company1: 10, company2: 10 }]    and want to define the model with var companies = ['company1', 'company2', ...]; Instead of hardcoding it just tp capture from backen and push in  model array companies. Is it possible to achieve

Comment: You would have to either override the reader or use Ext.Ajax.request ==> write the fields to the model ==> add the data to the store